# ROX volume mounted with readyOnly: false in container

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

So I have a ROX PVC and PV that I am mounting on a pod.

While mounting on a pod, I am setting readOnly to false:

```
Volumes:
  test-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim
    ClaimName:  pvc-1
    ReadOnly:   false
```

When I try to write to this pod by doing `kubectl exec command`, it goes through while I expect it to fail as the PV is created with AccessMode ROX.

Can someone please explain how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As per [kubernetes official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20uses%20volume,a%20single%20Pod.):

> Kubernetes uses volume access modes to match PersistentVolumeClaims and PersistentVolumes. In some cases, the volume access modes also constrain where the PersistentVolume can be mounted. Volume access modes do not enforce write protection once the storage has been mounted. Even if the access modes are specified as ReadWriteOnce, ReadOnlyMany, or ReadWriteMany, they don't set any constraints on the volume. For example, even if a PersistentVolume is created as ReadOnlyMany, there is no guarantee that it will be read-only. If the access modes are specified as ReadWriteOncePod, the volume is constrained and can be mounted on only a single Pod.

In your case you might have not mentioned ReadOnlyMany in your accessModes of your PVC, or using some pre-existing volume as a result the restrictions are not applied to the volume and you were able to perform write operations.

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks#pre-existing-persistent-disk) on ROX volumes provided by Google:

Clone an existing volume which contains the data or create a new dynamic volume, populate the data and convert that volume into readOnly In your PV and PVC manifest files configure the accessModes as ReadOnlyMany

By following the above steps you will be able to achieve the desired ROX functionality. Refer to below example manifest taken from Google documentation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: PV_NAME
spec:
  storageClassName: "STORAGE_CLASS_NAME"
  capacity:
    storage: DISK_SIZE
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  claimRef:
    namespace: PVC_NAMESPACE
    name: PVC_NAME
  csi:
    driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    volumeHandle: DISK_ID
    fsType: FS_TYPE
    readOnly: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: PVC_NAMESPACE
  name: PVC_NAME
spec:
  storageClassName: "STORAGE_CLASS_NAME"
  volumeName: PV_NAME
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: DISK_SIZE
```

Comment: I am specifying access mode as ReadOnlyMany in my PVC. The official documentation says accessMode does not guarantee write constraint but then what is the point of defining accessmode?

Comment: @codego123 as per this [official kubernetes blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/09/13/read-write-once-pod-access-mode-alpha/) access modes are the way you can define how durable storage is consumed. However, if you want to enforce any constraints you should use some other parameters like mentioned in the google documentation provided in the above solution.

Comment: @codego123 did you got time to go through my response...? revert back if you are still having some queries..

Comment: @Kanthiveer what is meant by durable storage?

Comment: @codego123 persistent storage or persistent volumes